# Is "gaining momentum"= "becoming popular"?

Tags: idioms

Consider the following sentence:

" the cloud computing is becoming popular among businesses"

**Question**: Can we replace "becoming popular" with "gaining momentum", so it would be:

" the cloud computing is gaining momentum among businesses"

Comment: It's not a very good metaphoric usage, because abstract concepts like "cloud computing" don't actually *move* in any meaningful way. It works a bit better if you refer more explicitly to *[an increase in] the **rate of uptake*** - for example, ***Use of** cloud computing is gaining momentum*. Or you could use ***gaining traction***, a more credible metaphoric allusion to ***establishing a foothold** [in a competitive market, for example]*.

Comment: No, the two phrases do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can, as it is constantly growing. However, *gaining momentum* in the literal sense means to acquire a constant rate of speed over time; the example given is more so a reference to the literal definition.

Answer (score 0):

**becoming popular** simply means that something was not popular and now it is more popular. it doesn't say anything about the rate at which it is changing.

Imagine a snowball rolling down a snowy hill: as it rolls, it picks up more snow and gets bigger. As it gets bigger, it rolls faster and faster. As it goes faster and faster, it picks up more and more snow... That's **gaining momentum**.